# copy partial lines in VI

Tags: vim, vi

There are a lot of different ways in which one can yank complete single/multiple lines. Is there a way in which we can copy partial lines in vi, like just 10 characters of the line.

Comment: I typically do e.g. <5><y><right arrow> to yank 5 chars to the right. I guess there are other ways as well :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would guess the most common partial yanks are:

`yaw`: yank the word the cursor is currently in
`2yaw`: yank the word the cursor in currently in and the next (2 words total)
`ya(`: yank the matched parentheses containing the cursor
`yf.`: yank from the cursor to the next `.`
`y$`: yank from the cursor to the end of the line

Any movement keys can be used.

Answer (score 10):

Cut and paste:

Position the cursor where you want to begin cutting.

1. Press **v** to select characters (or uppercase **V** to select whole lines).
2. Move the cursor to the end of what you want to cut.
3. Press **d** to cut (or **y** to copy).
4. Move to where you would like to paste.
5. Press **P** to paste before the cursor, or **p** to paste after.
6. Copy and paste is performed with the same steps except for step 4 where you would press **y** instead of **d**:

**d** = delete = cut

**y** = yank = copy

Resource:
[vim.wikia.com: Copy, cut and paste](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste)

Answer (score 4):

You can do `y`*Movement*, so for 10 characters: `y10l` yanks 10 characters from (and including) the current cursor position

Answer (score 2):

I prefer just pressing the v key, then using the cursor keys to move your selection. Then press the y key when you satisfied to yank the selection.

Answer (score 2):

you can also do

```
yt<char> - yank 'till char - i use that a lot

or y/<pattern>/ - yank until pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, with the cursor at the beginning of the line, type:

```
y10l
```

This yanks 10 characters to the right.  If you need to do this repeatedly for some reason, just add this temporary kep mapping:

```
:noremap ,m ^y10l
```

Which will yank the first 10 chars of any line every time you press `,m`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple lines to copy, try visual block mode,

```
" beginning of line
C-v
" up-down move 10j or 5k
10l
" copy & paste
y
p
```

more detail, see [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cut/copy_and_paste_using_visual_selection)

Answer (score 0):

This is one place mouse may actually beat keyboard, especially if the current mouse cursor is far from your copy target, or if you want to select multiple lines with partial start line or end line.

Use `:set mouse=a` to enable mouse support. Then select whatever irregular text blocks with mouse, and then press `y`